# Cloud DNS failed to load

Tags: google-cloud-dns

I'm trying to access Cloud DNS on a live account through the web console. This has worked for years, but currently is inaccessible. No settings have changed since it last worked.

The UI does not load, instead it shows this error:

"There was an error while loading /net-services/dns/zones?project=speedy-elf-XXXXXX. Please try again.

Request ID: xxxxxxxx506765"

Answer (score 1):

I faced this kind of issue one time, and also tried a lot of times, but the same error appeared. I was able to see the DNS console, but I was not able to add a new zone.

Probably my answer will sound a kind of "not useful", but I wait two days (meanwhile I tried a couple of times) and then, I was able to access and add the new Cloud DNS zone.

How long have you waiting until try again?

Comment: Figured it out, our credit card expired. The error message was just "Failed to load". Thank you though for your feedback. The error message is awfully vague!

Answer (score 1):

Confirming that an expired credit card was the issue for me as well. It's a very vague error message.